Can I use Windows 10 (22H2) for Intel 14 gen CPU?
I just bought a new PC with an Intel 14700KF CPU and I know it is recommended to Windows 11 for 12-14 gen CPU. However, I am really accustomed to using Windows 10, and I am wondering if the support for kernel scheduling of Windows 10 has been optimized enough for common use. Is there still a big performance difference between Windows 10 and 11 now? I am worried something like big cores stay idle while little cores is working at full capacity would happen. I‘ve heard it happened if using an early win10 version with intel 12 gen cpu.
Mostly, I use the PC to do image processing/simulation (MATLAB), C/C++ programming and AI algorithm testing.

Yes; Windows 10 supports modern AMD and Intel processors that have already been released. Have you tried running Windows 10?

yes of course, I have installed win10 system and it can run normally. But I am not sure if it can handle task scheduing well.

Is this to do with the 'newer' intel cores being essentially big/little style designs or as intel calls them P cores and E cores?

There is a measurable performance difference with 14th gen intel CPU's in windows 10 vs 11 with windows 11 scoring slightly better (gaming and productivity). It's not worth switching for if you are uncomfortable with how windows 11 works. Mind you that on october 14 2025 Windows 10 will be EOL !

Please integrate your question with what is your major use case for this PC, as it really depends on that.

@Ryan - So what performance metrics exactly are you worried about?

I am worried something like big cores stay idle while little cores is working at full capacity would happen. I‘ve heard it happened if using an early win10 version with intel 12 gen cpu.

[Edit] your question to include that clarification

Depending what software you run, Windows 10 might not use your CPU optimally, in some cases with drastic performance decrease read this excellent research. Although stock benchmarks do not show a big difference to Windows 11, in real life it's more complicated. In Windows 10 it really depends which power plan you run and what software you use.  @Silbee
